# What is humanize in Malli?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, schema, malli

I do not understand this concept. **malli.error/humanize**

I tried following up with the github link of Malli.
https://github.com/metosin/malli

Does humanize refer to the error statements that we can customize & add like in Java? Or does it mean that errors are printed in a more readable way?

And this is the code.

```
 (require '[malli.error :as me])

(-> Address
    (m/explain
      {:id "Lillan"
       :tags #{:artesan "coffee" :garden}
       :address {:street "Ahlmanintie 29"
                 :zip 33100
                 :lonlat [61.4858322, nil]}})
    (me/humanize))
;{:tags #{["should be a keyword"]}
; :address {:city ["missing required key"]
;           :lonlat [nil ["should be a double"]]}}
```

Comment: From the readme I get the idea that it produces the same as `m/explain` in a more readable way. It is also customizable so that the error messages are even more readable.

Comment: The readme https://github.com/metosin/malli#custom-error-messages , from where your example is from, lists many points and examples.  It primarily to get "human" friendly messages (other than "machine" friendly, that `exaplin` produces). The result is a datastructure, you have to deal with ("printing" will only help for developers, and it's not clear with what "Java"-feature you are trying to compare this)

Comment: @cfrick the java feature I was referring to was a simple try catch block. Was working on a project where we use default error messages for payloads, like null or invalid, etc. Or more specific about what in wrong I payload..

So I was trying to understand humanize enclosure with respect to the project's Java code.

Comment: "It primarily to get "human" friendly messages (other than "machine" friendly, that exaplin produces). "
This statement was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does humanize refer to the error statements that we can customize & add like in Java? Or does it mean that errors are printed in a more readable way?"

So both actually. We can customize it too.
And errors are printed in a more human-readable way.